# Updating Millions of Records Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created one query to update the 35 million records column,
but unfortunately, it took around more than one hour to process.
did I miss anything on the below query?

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR exp_cur IS
        SELECT
            DECODE(
              COLUMN_NAME,
              NULL, NULL,
              standard_hash(COLUMN_NAME)
            ) AS COLUMN_NAME
        FROM TABLE1;

    TYPE  nt_fName IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    fname nt_fName;

BEGIN
    OPEN exp_cur;

    FETCH exp_cur   BULK COLLECT INTO fname  LIMIT 1000000;

    CLOSE exp_cur;

    --Print data
    FOR idx IN 1 .. fname.COUNT
    LOOP
        UPDATE TABLE1 SET COLUMN_NAME=fname(idx);

        commit;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (idx||' '||fname(idx) );

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Maybe just `update table1 set column_name = standard_hash(COLUMN_NAME) where column_name is not null`? You are using very interesting way to update records.

Comment: ya @astentx but simple update statement took long time to update the records like more than a hour

Comment: Do you disable indexes with this column before update?

Comment: @astentx no I didn't disabled index

Comment: Is the fact that it takes over an hour actually a problem?  e.g. how often do you expect to run this query?  Only once or frequently? As others have said a simple query is likely to be faster than using a cursor.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I read few articles that BULK COLLECT will increase the update speed, but it seems its not

Comment: @Cyber BUL COLLECT will probably speed up a cursor, but it will generally be slower than doing a straight update

Comment: @Dijkgraaf without cursor, if we did it on simple loop then can we some performance?

Comment: For such massive update you may consider CTAS with calculation, disable indexes, truncate your table, fill it with data from new table with `/*+ append*/` hint and then rebuild indexes

Comment: @astentx can you suggest some good article to follow

Comment: @Cyber Trere's no magic "fast = true" option, so assuming bulk collect to be faster you should think of reasons: why it should be faster? What is the difference between it and direct update query, what mechanics is different? And my favourite: if you were a database what will you do for both statements and what will you do differently, which new feature will you be able to use in PL/SQL bulk collect compared to plain SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `bulk collect` used with a `forall` construction is generally faster than the equivalent row-by-row loop is because it applies all the updates in one shot, instead of laboriously stepping though the rows one at a time and launching 35 million separate update statements, each one requiring the database to search for the individual row before updating it. But what you have written (even when the bugs are fixed) is still a row-by-row loop with 35 million search and update statements, plus the additional overhead of populating a 700 MB array in memory, 35 million commits, and 35 million `dbms_output` messages. It has to be slower because it has significantly more work to do than a plain `update`.

If it is practical to copy the data to a new table, `insert` will be a lot faster than `update`. At the end you can reapply any grants, indexes and constraints to the new table, rename both tables and drop the old one. You can also `insert /*+ parallel enable_parallel_dml */` (or prior to Oracle 12c, you have to `alter session enable parallel dml` separately.) You could define the new table as `nologging` during the copy, but check with your DBA as that can affect replication and backups, though that might not matter if this is a test system. This will all need careful scripting if it's going to form part of a routine workflow.

Comment: Thanks..!!! It worked for me copy the data to new table and truncate the old table data and then I inserted from new table to old table.. so insert is faster when compared to update... :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is updating all records of `TABLE1` in each loop. (It loops 35 million times and in each loop updating 35 million records, That's why it is taking time)

You can simply use a single update statement as follows:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COLUMN_NAME = standard_hash(COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

So, If you want to use the `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL` then you can use it as follows:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR EXP_CUR IS
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE1
     WHERE COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL;

    TYPE NT_FNAME IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    FNAME NT_FNAME;
BEGIN
    OPEN EXP_CUR;
    FETCH EXP_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO FNAME LIMIT 1000000;
    FORALL IDX IN FNAME.FIRST..FNAME.LAST
        UPDATE TABLE1
           SET COLUMN_NAME = STANDARD_HASH(COLUMN_NAME)
         WHERE COLUMN_NAME = FNAME(IDX);

    COMMIT;
    CLOSE EXP_CUR;
END;
/
```

Comment: Even simple statement took that much time like 180 min , so I have used BULK COLLECT method, but this also taking more than 1 hour

Comment: The simple update will be always faster than the loop and bulk collect.

Comment: no I have tried simple statement but still facing same issue like processing more than one hour

Comment: Alternatively I tried CTAS method, but its like a copying data to new table after that we need to give table permission, altering partitions, recreating index,constraints

Comment: it throws error   Error report -
ORA-06550: line 10, column 37:
PLS-00321: expression 'NT_FNAME' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 26:
PLS-00302: component 'FIRST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 11, column 17:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Yeap, My bad!! Use the `FNAME` instead of `NT_FNAME` as updated in the answer now!!

Comment: FNAME (I) is missed

Comment: But why it should be faster if it is the same as just plain update?

Comment: `FNAME(IDX)` is used in the loop and the loop variable was `I` so it was throwing an error. that is just a typo. and it is using the `FORALL` that's why it should be faster.

Comment: I triggered this query for small table, but normal statement executed quickly like 2 seconds, but this one running still

Comment: I am again repeating that a normal update is always faster than a loop approach in any database.

Comment: ok thanks for the time and your replay, I prefer to use CTAS method